Install ruby 3.3.x with rvm, missing psych gym
I'm installing ruby 3.3.x with rvm by rvm install 3.3.5, no apparent error shown. However, I noticed psych gem folder is empty,even though it's there in the gem list as psych 5.1.2.  this causing problems when I try to gem install/uninstall anything, since it keeps saying, cannot load file --psych. Any ideas how to fix this issue please. Thanks in advance.
env setting:
<20240904 10:03:07>$ rvm use 3.3.5
Using /home/idm/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.5
<20240904 10:03:22>$ which ruby
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/bin/ruby
<20240904 10:03:35>$ ruby -v
ruby 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 revision ef084cc8f4) [x86_64-linux]
<20240904 10:03:38>$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.16
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 patchlevel 100) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/idm/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.5
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/idm/.gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/idm/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/idm/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/idm/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.5
     - /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/idm/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.5/bin
     - /home/idm/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.3.5@global/bin
     - /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/bin
     - /home/idm/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /home/idm/.local/bin
     - /home/idm/bin
<20240904 10:03:52>$

error:
<20240904 10:05:53>$ gem install bundler
<internal:/home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require': cannot load such file -- psych (LoadError)
        from <internal:/home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems.rb:594:in `load_yaml'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1240:in `_load'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/safe_marshal/visitors/to_ruby.rb:351:in `call_method'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/safe_marshal/visitors/to_ruby.rb:182:in `visit_Gem_SafeMarshal_Elements_UserDefined'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/safe_marshal/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `visit'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/safe_marshal/visitors/to_ruby.rb:28:in `visit'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/safe_marshal.rb:71:in `load'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/safe_marshal.rb:61:in `safe_load'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/source.rb:139:in `fetch_spec'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/resolver/api_specification.rb:93:in `spec'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:99:in `add_always_install'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:318:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:198:in `install_gem'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:223:in `block in install_gems'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:216:in `each'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:216:in `install_gems'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:162:in `execute'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command.rb:326:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:255:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:194:in `process_args'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:152:in `run'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:56:in `run'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/bin/gem:12:in `<main>'


<20240904 10:06:05>$ irb
3.3.5 :001 > require 'psych'
<internal:/home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require': cannot load such file -- psych (LoadError)
        from <internal:/home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:136:in `require'
        from (irb):1:in `<main>'
        from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/irb-1.13.1/exe/irb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /home/idm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.5/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
3.3.5 :002 >



Rpm -qa|grep libyaml returns libyaml-0.1.4-11.e17_0.x86_64

What is the full error message you actually receive when running the gem commands? I am assuming you have tried running gem install psych

Any gem install/uninstall, irb require 'psych' all give the same error: cannot load such file --psych.  Could it be my version of libyaml is too old. I have ruby 3.1.2 on the same server, it's working fine

Please edit your question to show a full example of a command invocation and the full verbatim output, including the full stack trace. Also make sure that you are using the right Ruby, i.e., that you have correctly installed RVM and have correctly selected the desired ruby version. The output of which ruby and gem env helps here. Please add this to your question (not just as a comment),

I just updated the question with more detail requested

The issue was due to libyaml-devel was missing, causing rvm install 3.3.x unable to install psych gem.
